# How to solve this equation involving the floor function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve  the equation
$$\left[ \frac x {1!} \right]  +  \left[ \frac x {2!} \right] +\left[ \frac x {3!} \right]+\cdots +  \left[ \frac x {10!} \right]  =1001,$$
where $[ r]$ stands for the integer part of a real number $r,$
in the integers? I can do it with Maple only.

Comment: First off, you can simplify it. If $ x $ is a solution, then of course $ x > 0 $ and thus $ x \le 1001 $. This implies that each term with a denominator bigger than $ 1001 $ will vanish, so only the first six terms survive ($ 6! = 720 $). You can surely simplify it even more by noting that, for instance, the sixth term must vanish as well (can't have $ x \ge 720 $), and so on. Other than that, I see no smarter ways than trial-and-error...

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to be an integer?

Comment: @ Daniel R: Can you kindly explain the purpose of your edit? As far as I know it, $[r]$ is a standard notation for the integer part of  a real number $r$.

Comment: @ user37238 : Yes, it is stated in the question.

Comment: @user64494 you state that $[r]$ stands for the integer part in the real $r$. That is exactly what $\left\lfloor r\right\rfloor$ does

Comment: user37238, You might be right, just roll it back if you're unhappy with it. For me $\lfloor . \rfloor$ is much more obvious, since it's more or less self-explanatory.

Comment: @derpy: Thank you for the interest to the question and its simplification. That was asked at a school math olimpiad.

Comment: Also, when you're adding a space between @ and the user name, the user won't get pinged.

Comment: @Daniel R: I am learned to respect the others. Please don't change my notation. Of course,  you may use $\left\lfloor \cdot \right \rfloor$ in your posts.

Comment: I'm not being disrespectful, I'm sorry if you were offended, I was just trying to be helpful. I sincerely thought that you were trying to mimic the floor symbols. I wasn't aware of the fact that [] notation is standard (if it is).

Comment: Wikipedia: "Carl Friedrich Gauss introduced the square bracket notation  $[x]$ for the floor function in his third proof of quadratic reciprocity (1808).This remained the standard in mathematics until Kenneth E. Iverson introduced the names "floor" and "ceiling" and the corresponding notations $\lfloor x\rfloor$  and $\lceil x \rceil$  in his 1962 book A Programming Language.Both notations are now used in mathematics..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's find $\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$ where $f(x)=\sum_{r=1}^{10}\left[\frac{x}{r!}\right]$

Note that you can write numerator as $\sum\dfrac{x}{k!} + \text{error}$

Note that this $\text{error}$ is not more that $10$ and hence we have denominator as $x$ which is very large as it tends to infinity and it will make it zero.

We also note that $e-1=\sum_{k\ge1}\dfrac{1}{k!}$

Hence, limit is $\sum_{k=1}^{10}\dfrac{1}{k!}\approx e-1$

Now you can start you initial guess near $\dfrac{1001}{e-1}\approx \dfrac{1001}{1.718}\approx 582.65$

This gives us integer $x=584$

Also $f(x+r)=f(x) \forall r\in[0,1)\implies x\in[584,585) $

Comment: @Aversome: I disagree with $ \lim_{x\to\infty}[x]=x-\{x\}=x-0=x$.

Comment: @user64494 That should not be 0. Corrected. Its just that {x} is negligible compared to x

Comment: @Aversome:  I disagree with $\lim_{x\to\infty}[x]=x-\{x\}=x $ too. I don't find that as a math proof. I wonder the upvoter.

Comment: Let me edit so that it becomes more rigorous.

Comment: @user64494 Do you agree now? I have edited

Comment: @Awersome : You wrote "This gives us integer $ x=584$".. In fact, you have to check $582,\,583,\,584$. Can those difficult calculations be shortened?

Comment: @user64494 Those are not difficult. With right steps they would take 1-2 minutes. You have to just calculate till 5! after which they are zero. Also, most numbers will remain same. Some will be incremented by 1.

Answer (score 3):

Using inequalities reduce the problem, as
$$
y-1< [y] \le y
$$
we have
$$
\left(\frac{x}{1!}-1\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{x}{10!}-1\right) < 1001 \le \frac{x}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{x}{10!}
$$
simplifying into
$$
x\left(\frac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{10!}\right)-10 < 1001 \le x\left(\frac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{10!}\right)
$$
solving the two inequalities in $x$ gives (its just computation)
$$
582\le x \le 589
$$
Then, I don't really know how to do... trying all values or doing bissection can be the only way to solve this, as floor function is a bit random...
Trying all integers between 582 and 589 we find the solution $x=584$ as previously said.

Comment: By dichotomie you mean bisection?

Comment: yes thanks, dichotomie is the french word ^^

Comment: @Vintarel: I like your proof except "its just computation".

Comment: if you denote $E = (1/1!)+\cdots+(1/10!)$ then a) $x<1001/E<589$ and b), $x\ge 1011/E > 582$

Answer (score 2):

Let's play with

$$f(x)=\sum_{r=1}^{10}\left[\frac{x}{r!}\right]$$

$f(90)=153$

$f(100)=170$

$f(150)=257$

$f(500)=857$

I found a pattern. $\frac{153}{90}\approx\frac{170}{100}\approx\frac{257}{170}\approx\frac{857}{500}\approx 1.7$

With higher numbers, error is of max $ 0.02$

Hence, we should start guessing our number near $\frac{1001}{1.7}=588.82$

$f(590)=1011$

$f(580)=944$

Calculation must not be tough now. Just see how which fraction changes when you increase to $581$

$f(581)=995$

$f(582)=998$

$f(583)=999$

$f(584)=1001$

and we are done.

We also could have used $1.71$ which is better approximation with large numbers.

This yield initial guess of $585.38$. More closer.

This is related with $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$$
My calculator plots a somewhat converging graph.

Let me see if I can find the limit. It seems to be $e-1$

Comment: @Aversome: The questions arise: i) How to solve it in the general case, i.e. with an integer $N$ instead of $1001$? ii) How to find all the real solutions of the equation under consideration?

Comment: @user64494 Let me post another answer.

Comment: @user64494 See my another answer.

Comment: @Aversome: Feel free to do that. You may add your second answer to the first one.

Comment: @user64494 That would become too long. I hate long answers